# Usar a primeira parte do split

Tags: c#, split

Gostaria de saber se tem como usar o `split` para fazer apenas uma divisão, *por exemplo*, tenho o seguinte texto: **dia_24_06_18**.

Queria que separasse pelo **_** na matriz assim:

```
[0] - dia
[1] - 24_06_18
```

Comment: Sim Luísa: dessa forma: `string c = "dia_24_06_18";` `var res = c.Split(new[] { '_' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);` vai ser `res[0]` e `res[1]` **Exemplo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/wXSimw